# Conditional formatting of cells that contain formulae but no values

Tags: excel

I like to use conditional formatting to provide extra information in my spreadsheets, but I now find myself stuck.

In a spreadsheet of cargo items, I have a column (calculated; it contains a formula) for density. Previously, it just changed text colour, so empty cells didn't stand out. But now that I'm trying to really show up any anomalies with a bright background, I've found that it (or its sibling) highlights all the "empty" cells that don't have calculated values yet.

[image: Blank cells aren't blank.]

The formula I'm using is `WHERE THE VALUE IS GREATER THAN 10` for the upper out-of-bounds area, and `=AND($L2<3,NOT(ISBLANK($L2)))` for the lower area. I've also tried using `$L2>0` instead of the `NOT` clause.

The ideal would be changing the upper and lower density limits based on the material it's claimed to be in the description field (column B), but I'm not bothering with that until I get this working.

Is the formula I'm using right, or should I tweak it? Would I be better off just using `GREATER THAN 0` and then formatting the right densities blue as `=AND($L2<10, $L2>3)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think counter-intuitively it is the

```
WHERE THE VALUE IS GREATER THAN 10
```

formula that may be doing the damage.

You probably have a formula in column L on the lines of

```
IF (<cell in previous column is empty> , "" , <some calculation>)
```

and when the conditional formula compares the result to 10 it actually gives TRUE because a text string is considered to be greater than a number in this context.

I suggest trying two things:-

(1) Change the colour of the     WHERE THE VALUE IS GREATER THAN 10  formatting rule to see if the 'empty' cells are highlighted in that colour.

(2) Instead of     WHERE THE VALUE IS GREATER THAN 10, use a formula like

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(L2),L2>10)
```

- this works for me.

Comment: I thought that might have been what was stopping it, but I couldn't figure out why - it didn't occur to me that it sees empty text strings as values. The formula you suggested works perfectly - many thanks!